# Sketch3: How to draw a line start from the center of a circle

Tags: sketch-app

I want to draw a line start from a center of a circle, but I haven't figured it out. I have tried with `cmd`, `alt` or `shift`, none of them works.

Comment: Hello Leo and welcome to GraphicDesign! Let us know if you have any questions about how the site works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you are saying here, but just create a line and move it until the guides are exactly centered.

[image]